# Forwarding domain path to other domains with a different port

Tags: domain-name-system, forwarding

I was wondering if forwarding like this was possible with any service like godaddy/dyndns/etc:

http://www.mydomain.com/path1 ---> http://mydomain.com:1234/ 
http://www.mydomain.com/path2 ---> http://domain2.com:5688/test1  
http://www.mydomain.com/path3 ---> http://domain2.com:9873/test2

It would also be nice if the browser didn't show the ports, etc.

Comment: For the time being, browsers will always show the port if it's not 80 or 443.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you would need is not a DNS-based solution, but a [**Reverse Proxying**](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reverse_proxy) solution.

Most of the predominant web server technologies on the market offer this functionality to some extent, like:
[Apache (with mod_proxy)](http://www.apachetutor.org/admin/reverseproxies), [IIS (with Application Request Routing)](http://learn.iis.net/page.aspx/659/reverse-proxy-with-url-rewrite-v2-and-application-request-routing/) and [nginx](http://tumblr.intranation.com/post/766288369/using-nginx-reverse-proxy).

I don't have any experience with hosted reverse proxying, but I know that some hosting providers offer this capability.